# What C construct would allow me to 'reverse reference' an array?

Tags: c

Looking for an elegant way (or a construct with which I am unfamiliar) that allows me to do the equivalent of 'reverse referencing' an array. That is, say I have an integer array

**handle[number] = nameNumber**

Sometimes I know the **number** and need the nameNumber, but sometimes I only know the **nameNumber** and need the matching **[number]** in the array.

The integer **nameNumber** values are each unique, that is, no two **nameNumbers** that are the same, so every **[number]** and **nameNumber** pair are also unique.

Is there a good way to 'reverse reference' an array value (or some other construct) without having to sweep the entire array looking for the matching value, (or having to update and keep track of two different arrays with reverse value sets)?

Comment: you want a dictionary or a hash structure. uthash is a simple hash for c: https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html

Comment: As an example C++ has [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) but C itself has nothing, you roll your own or use a pre-existing implementation. As the C array notation (`x[y]`) cannot be used for anything but arrays, though, you need to call this as a function, like `dict_find(x, y)` or `dict_set(x, y, z)`.

Comment: You need to specify your constraints.   The minimum space implementation is just a linear search through the values of the array.  The minimum search time implementation is probably a hash table. The minimum update time may be something else.  Which operation needs to be fastest? What are the pace constraints? Does it need to support growing and shrinking?  You need to answer these questions before we can say which way is "good".

Comment: Just loop through the array elements until you find `nameNumber` and return the index...

Comment: What you're describing is called a "search" or a "find".   In general terms, it steps over elements of the array in some manner, until it finds a match.   If the array is sorted, you can use `bsearch()` function, which will return a pointer to the element (or NULL if not present), which can then be converted to an index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's acceptable for you to use C++ and `boost` libraries. If yes you can use [`boost::bimap<X, Y>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

> Boost.Bimap is a bidirectional maps library for C++. With Boost.Bimap you can create associative containers in which both types can be used as key. A bimap can be thought of as a combination of a std::map and a std::map.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted and you know the length of it, you could binary search for the element in the array. This would be an O(n log(n)) search instead of you doing O(n) search through the array. Divide the array in half and check if the element at the center is greater or less than what you're looking for, grab the half of the array your element is in, and divide in half again. Each decision you make will eliminate half of the elements in the array. Keep this process going and you'll eventually land on the element you're looking for.